# I am using jupyter for the 1st time.This is the first example I am practising.My code is below:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 viz = cdf[['Quantity Ordered','Price Each']]
2 df.hist(column='Price Each')

Error:
...
    210     plot_backend = _get_plot_backend(backend)
--> 211     return plot_backend.hist_frame(
    212         data,
    213         column=column,
....

    414     if naxes == 0:
--> 415         raise ValueError("hist method requires numerical columns, nothing to plot.")
    416 
    417     fig, axes = _subplots(

ValueError: hist method requires numerical columns, nothing to plot.
```

Comment: What data does your "Price each" column contain?

Comment: Show some dataset

Comment: **Numeric value** @Jason Shawn D' Souza

Comment: Order ID                Product            Quantity Ordered     Price Each                                                           
    295665   Macbook Pro Laptop 1                     1700
    295666   LG Washing Machine 1                      600.0
    295667   USB-C Charging Cable 1                    11.95
   295668           27in FHD Monitor         1                    149.99

Comment: Can you double check the data types of the column (using df.dtypes). This could be because it might be numeric but stored as a string for some reason.

Comment: **It shows as object** @Jason Shawn D' Souza

Comment: df["Price Each"] = df["Price Each"].astype(str).astype(int)    .Try converting the column to int with the code and then the hist should work. Please let me know